# Facebook customer support?

Tags: facebook

My brother passed away suddenly two weeks ago. There has been amazing outpouring of love and support on his Facebook page. The problem is, my parents just joined Facebook and they were not yet "friends" with him. I need to make our parents "friends" with him, so that they can view all of the wonderful entries on his page. We can't get into his account to accept the friend requests.

Does anyone know a way to contact Facebook, and have them accept these friend requests on his behalf?

Answer (score 2):

Try reaching this URL `http://www.facebook.com/help/`

Click on "Report an issue"

Click on "Something You Can't See"

Click on "How do I report something on Facebook that I can't see?"

And finally, "**please file a report here.**"